# How to save data to a specific folder and add header line in csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, save

I have a dictionary with the following code:

```
def _fetch_currencies():
    f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json')
    str_f = f.readall().decode('utf-8')
    currencies_lst = json.loads(str_f)
    sorted_currencies = sorted(currencies_lst.items())
    return(sorted_currencies)
```

This is used to fetch currencies from a website.

I need to save the currencies with columns "code" and "name" in which the currencies' codes and names are saved to a specific folder.

I have some code for saving but it always saves to my python folder when i need it elsewhere

the code is as follows:

```
def save_currencies(_fetch_currencies, filename):   
    with open(filename, 'w') as my_csv:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
        csv_writer.writerows(_fetch_currencies)
```

I am also not sure how to add the column titles at the top of the save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry for my bad English)

You can add header line in begin of your file manually:

```
def save_currencies(_fetch_currencies, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as my_csv:
        my_csv.write('code,name\n')   # add header line
        csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
        csv_writer.writerows(_fetch_currencies)
```

If you want to change directory, you need to append path to it in `filename` variable.

Remember the difference between absolute and relative paths. If you pass as `filename` argument string `'output.txt'` it will be placed in current directory. Pass absolute path to target directory, for example: `'/home/username/output.txt'` or relative path `'../output.txt'` for write in parent directory relative to current python directory.

To concatenate directory and filename you can use `os.path.join` function

Answer (score 1):

First assign the path to the folder you want to save the file, then write the headers in the csv file. Using the `iteritems()` method you iterate through your dictionary and write each key and value at the end.

```
def save_currencies(_fetch_currencies, filename):   
    with open("path/to/folder/{}".format(filename), 'wb') as my_csv:
       csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
       csv_writer.writerow(["code","name"])  
       for k,v in _fetch_currencies.iteritems(): 
          csv_writer.writerow([k,v])
```